# How do I filter multiple items on React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new on React and I'm struggling to apply multiple filters on React. I need to filter a list of vehicles applying filters by: Year, Price Range, New or Old vehicles. I don't know to do it and I'm kind of lost searching and watching tutorials. Could someone help me?

I'm being able to apply each filter individually, but not together. I was thinking to add a type of filter on my code.

Here is my code:

Data:

```
const faixaValor = useMemo(
    () => [
      { ID: 1, PriceRangeID: 1, value: '0-20', Name: 'R$0 - R$20.000' },
      { ID: 2, PriceRangeID: 2, value: '20-40', Name: 'R$20.001 - R$40.000' },
      { ID: 3, PriceRangeID: 3, value: '40-60', Name: 'R$40.001 - R$60.000' },
      { ID: 4, PriceRangeID: 4, value: '60-100', Name: 'R$60.001 - R$100.000' },
    ],
    []
)

const anos = useMemo(
    () => [
        { ID: 1, YearID: 1, value: 2012, Name: '2012' },
        { ID: 2, YearID: 2, value: 2013, Name: '2013' },
        { ID: 3, YearID: 3, value: 2014, Name: '2014' },
        { ID: 4, YearID: 4, value: 2015, Name: '2015' },
        { ID: 5, YearID: 5, value: 2016, Name: '2016' },
        { ID: 6, YearID: 6, value: 2017, Name: '2017' },
        { ID: 7, YearID: 7, value: 2018, Name: '2018' },
    ],
    []
)
```

My Checkbox:

```
<Checkbox 
         value={newChecked} 
         onChange={event => setNewChecked(event.target.checked)} 
         title="Novos"
         />
<Checkbox 
         value={usedChecked} 
         onChange={event => setUsedChecked(event.target.checked)} 
         title="Usados"
         />
```

Search Component passing props:

```
<Search 
       priceRange={priceRange}
       year={year}
       newChecked={newChecked} 
       usedChecked={usedChecked}
/>
```

The Search component:

```
function Search(props) {

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const [error, setError] = useState(false)
const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(false)
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)
const [vehicles, setVehicles] = useState([])
const [search, setSearch] = useState(false)
const [filteredVehicles, setFilteredVehicles] = useState([])
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([])
const apiService = ApiService

// Infinite loading by page - 10 in 10 vehicles
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    setError(false)
    getVehicles()        
}, [search, pageNumber])

useEffect(() => {
    filterVehicles(vehicles)
}, [props])

// Observe page position
const observer = useRef()
const lastVehicleElement = useCallback(node => {
    if(loading) 
    return 
    if(observer.current) observer.current.disconnect()
    observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        if(entries[0].isIntersecting && hasMore) {
            setPageNumber(prevPageNumber => prevPageNumber + 1)
        }
    })
    if(node) observer.current.observe(node)
}, [loading, hasMore])


async function getVehicles() {

    await apiService.ListVehicle(pageNumber)
        .then(res => {
            setVehicles(prevVehicles => {
                if(isFiltered) {
                    return [...new Set([...prevVehicles, ...res])]
                } else {
                    return null
                }
            })
            setHasMore(res.length > 0)
            setLoading(false)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            setError(true)
            throw new Error (err.message)
        })
}

async function filterVehicles(vehicles) {
    /* Radius - No need 'cause of the API
    if(props.radius) {}
    */

    // Year
    if(props.year) {
        const filterYear = await vehicles.filter(
            vehicle => (vehicle.YearFab == props.year)
        )
        await setFilters(prev => ({ ...prev, year: true }))
        await setFilteredVehicles(filterYear)
        console.log(filters)
    }

    // Price Range
    if(props.priceRange) {

        let prices = props.priceRange.split('-')
        let priceMin = parseInt(prices[0])
        let priceMax = parseInt(prices[1])

        const filterMin = await vehicles.filter(
            vehicle => ((parseInt(vehicle.Price)/1000) > priceMin)
        )
        const finalFilter = await filterMin.filter(
            vehicle => ((parseInt(vehicle.Price)/1000) < priceMax)
        )
        await setFilteredVehicles(finalFilter)
        await setFilters(prev => ({ ...prev, priceRange: true }))
        console.log(filters)
    }

    // Both checkboxes true
    if(!props.newChecked & !props.usedChecked) {
        return null
    } else {
        // Checkbox new True
        if(props.newChecked & !props.usedChecked) {
            const filterNew = await vehicles.filter(
                vehicle => !vehicle.KM
            ) 
            await setFilteredVehicles(filterNew)
            await setFilters(prev => ({ ...prev, filterNew: true }))
        }
        // Checkbox used True
        if(props.usedChecked & !props.newChecked) {
            const filterUsed = await vehicles.filter(
                vehicle => vehicle.KM
            )
            await setFilteredVehicles(filterUsed)
            await setFilters(prev => ({ ...prev, filterUsed: true }))
        }
    } 
    if(props.newChecked & props.usedChecked) {
        await setFilteredVehicles(vehicles)
        await setFilters([])
    }        
}

function isFiltered() {

    if(props.newChecked || props.usedChecked || props.year || props.priceRange) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

async function handleClick() {

    setVehicles([])

    let totalPages = 3;
    for(let i=1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        await apiService.ListVehicle(i)
            .then(res => {
                setVehicles(prevVehicles => {  
                    return [...new Set([...prevVehicles, ...res])] 
                })
            })
    }
    filterVehicles(vehicles)
    setVehicles(filteredVehicles)
    setSearch(true)        
}

async function handleFilter() {
    setVehicles([])
    setFilteredVehicles([])
}

return (
    <Fragment>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Buscar</button>  
        <button onClick={() => handleFilter()}>Limpa</button> 

        { isFiltered() ? (
            <div>
            <h1 className="filtered">Filtrados</h1>
            <div className="grid">
                { filteredVehicles.map(vehicle => (
                    <div className="vehicle-card-item" key={vehicle.ID}>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <img src={vehicle.Image} alt={vehicle.Make}/>
                                <div className="vehicle-details">
                                    <div className="vehicle-main-info">
                                        <h2>{vehicle.Make} {vehicle.Model}</h2>
                                        <h3>{vehicle.Version}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="vehicle-price">
                                        <strong>R${vehicle.Price}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="year-and-km">
                                        <h4>{vehicle.YearFab} / {vehicle.YearModel}</h4>
                                        <h3>{vehicle.KM} km</h3> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>   
                ))
                }
            </div>
            </div>
        ) : (
            // { search &&
            <div className="grid">
                { vehicles.map((vehicle, index) => { 
                    if (vehicles.length === index + 1) { 
                    return <div className="vehicle-card-item" ref={lastVehicleElement} key={vehicle.ID}>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <img src={vehicle.Image} alt={vehicle.Make}/>
                                <div className="vehicle-details">
                                    <div className="vehicle-main-info">
                                        <h2>{vehicle.Make} {vehicle.Model}</h2>
                                        <h3>{vehicle.Version}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="vehicle-price">
                                        <strong>R${vehicle.Price}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="year-and-km">
                                        <h4>{vehicle.YearFab} / {vehicle.YearModel}</h4>
                                        <h3>{vehicle.KM} km</h3> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul> 
                        { loading ? ( <Loading /> ): null} 
                    </div> 
                    } else {
                    return <div className="vehicle-card-item" key={vehicle.ID}>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <img src={vehicle.Image} alt={vehicle.Make}/>
                                <div className="vehicle-details">
                                    <div className="vehicle-main-info">
                                        <h2>{vehicle.Make} {vehicle.Model}</h2>
                                        <h3>{vehicle.Version}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="vehicle-price">
                                        <strong>R${vehicle.Price}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="year-and-km">
                                        <h4>{vehicle.YearFab} / {vehicle.YearModel}</h4>
                                        <h3>{vehicle.KM} km</h3> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>  
                    </div> 
                    }
                })}
            </div>
        )}     
    </Fragment>
)

}

export default Search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified it a bit, leaving the API logic and search selection JSX out. The idea is that you do not try to set the filtered list of vehicles as state, instead you just compute it every time the element is rendered.

```js
const vehicles = [
  {name: "foo1", year: 2020},
  {name: "foo2", year: 2020},
  {name: "bar1", year: 2019},
  {name: "bar2", year: 2019},
  {name: "baz1", year: 2018},
  {name: "baz2", year: 2018},
];

const SearchWithFilter = () => {
  // Should be set to number if we want only vehicles from that
  // year, or null if it is disabled.
  const [yearFilter, setYearFilter] = React.useState(null)
  const [nameFilter, setNameFilter] = React.useState(null)

  const applyYearFilter = (vehicle) => {
    // Keep all cars if the year filter is not set, otherwise
    // only keep the cars which meet the year filter.
    return !yearFilter || yearFilter === vehicle.year
  }

  const applyNameFilter = (vehicle) => {
    return !nameFilter || vehicle.name.includes(nameFilter)
  }

  const filteredVehicles = vehicles
       .filter(applyYearFilter) // Remove all vehicles which do not match the year filter
       .filter(applyNameFilter) // Remove all vehicles which do not match the name filter
       .map((vehicle) => <p>{vehicle.name}</p>) // Create JSX for each vehicle object

  return (
        <div>
         <h1>Filter on year</h1>
         <button onClick={() => setYearFilter(2020)}>2020</button>
         <button onClick={() => setYearFilter(2019)}>2019</button>
         <button onClick={() => setYearFilter(null)}>Clear</button>
         <h1>Filter on name:</h1>
         <input onChange={(event) => setNameFilter(event.target.value)} />
         <h1>Results:</h1>
         {filteredVehicles}
      </div>
  )
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Addono/1pd2a0ob/

Comment: Sorry, for the delay in answering I didn't understand properly. But I was thinking maybe trying to use REDUX to simplify the states managment. Then I think I'd also simplify the filter method. Am I right? (I still learning REDUX, not sure if my statement is correct)

Comment: @WilliamS.Takayama Redux isn't a silver bullet: https://redux.js.org/faq/general#when-should-i-use-redux. To me, your problem seems simple enough to be solved with vanilla React, as your state is relatively simple. I think the key to improving your solution is to limit your state to the configuration of the filters. Your original solution tries to also store the computed result in the state, which is unnecessary additional complexity of your state.

Comment: Anyway, I implemented a full example. It only has two filters, but I hope the pattern is clear and allows you to create your own filters.

Comment: Thank you very much! It clarified to me that my solution was really messy and I was getting lost...